# How to add grammarly plugin in laravel forms?

Tags: php, laravel, forms, textarea

I have this file

```
@section('content')

    <form method="post" action="{{ route('member.articles.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data"
          onSubmit="submit.disabled=true; submit.value='{{ __('Submitting ...') }}'; return true;">
        @csrf

        <div class="card bg-light">
            <div class="card-header">{{ __('Add Article') }}</div>
            <div class="card-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ Form::label('title', __('Title')) }}
                    {{ Form::text('title', old('title'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => true, 'maxlength' => 190]) }}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" style="display: none">
                    {{ Form::label('slug', __('Slug(URL Key)')) }}
                    {{ Form::text('slug', old('slug'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'maxlength' => 190]) }}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ Form::label('category', __('Category')) }}
                    {{ Form::select('category', $categories, old('category'),
                        ['class' => 'form-control select2', 'required' => true]) }}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ Form::label('content', __('Content')) }}
                    {{ Form::textarea('content', old('content'), ['class' => 'form-control text-editor'])}}
                </div>
```

And i want to add grammarly plugin in content area.

FYI: https://developer.grammarly.com/docs/api/editor-sdk/

I tried this but not working:-

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('content', __('Content')) }}
    <grammarly-editor-plugin>

        {{ Form::textarea('content', old('content'), ['class' => 'form-control text-editor'])}}

    </grammarly-editor-plugin>            
</div>
```